# instantiate object with *new* keyword and use property inside class with *this* keyword

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm coming from mainly JS/TS world (NestJS/Angular) and recently i start to building Flutter apps..
i have 2 main questions

1. there is any difference when instantiate object with or without **new** keyword?
   i saw examples in flutter when people use `new Row(children: [Text('Foo'), Text('Bar'),],)` instead of just `Row(...)`
   if there is a difference which one is better to use?
2. inside of my Dart classes in flutter app, i can both use **this.property** and **property** again there is any difference and if so which one is better and why?

example:

```
class Person { 
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  getNameAge() => '${this.name} is ${this.age}';
  getNameAge2() => '$name is $age';
}
```

both looks the same to me

```
void main() {
  
  final p = Person('dan', 22);
  final p2 = new Person('ben', 20);
  
  print(p.getNameAge());      // dan is 22
  print(p2.getNameAge2());    // ben is 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword is optional in Dart and I think the general consensus is, today, to not use it.

The use of `this` is useful if you have multiple variables with the same name but in different scope. E.g. (this is just an example. You would not make a `setA` method in Dart but use properties):

```
class A {
  int a;
  A(this.a);
  
  void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

Here we use `this` to distinguish between the argument `a` and the class variable `a`. But if you don't have variables with the same name (but in different scope), the use of `this` is optional. In some projects, you still use `this` to make it more clear that you are referring to a class variable even if it is not needed.